# Making a form that only appears if prerequisites are met

Tags: html, forms, hidden, survey

I'm trying to make a form that asks a few questions and I can't figure out how to make a question that will only appear if you select like Yes and won't show if you click No.

Like (just a basic example):

```
Do you use any social media site?
Yes/No (in a dropdown)
```

and if `Yes` is selected a new question will appear below:

Which do you use?

- Facebook
- Twitter

etc.

and this question wont show up if no is selected.

Comment: To large question .. And to gie element : use jquery , else you can directly use https://www.limesurvey.org .

Answer (score 0):

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/b1y36sne/1/

```html
<select id="social" name="social" onchange="change_fc()" placeholder="">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Do you use any social media site?</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<div id="which" style="display: none;">
<select id="which_sm" name="which">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Which do you use?</option>
    <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
    <option value="twitter">Twitter</option>
</select>
</div>
<script>
function change_fc() {
    var the_value = document.getElementById("social").value;
    if(the_value=="yes") {
        document.getElementById('which').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('which').style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks! is it possible to add another question that only appears if "Yes" is selected, like "How often (for example)"

Comment: i'm a complete beginner, how would I go about doing this? Thanks and sorry haha

Answer (score 0):

@KSykes I have done something similar in the past and used a mapping xml file. I would load a usercontrol based on conditions selected by the user. This usercontrol's attributes like name, path etc are written on your map file. I think this is the best approach as you can make as many different usercontrols as you like. Nothing is hard coded, you simply make a different map.xml file for different conditions...even the question could come from a usercontrol and loaded from a path written in your map file.